# Faster way to identify and compare rows based on matching conditions within a dataframe having millions of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below.

[image: Actual Dataframe]

```
         Date   Fruit level_0    Num    Color
0  2013-11-25   Apple     DF2   22.1      Red
1  2013-11-24  Banana     DF1   22.1   Yellow
2  2013-11-24  Banana     DF2  122.1   Yellow
3  2013-11-23  Celery     DF1   10.2    Green
4  2013-11-24  Orange     DF1    8.6   Orange
5  2013-11-24  Orange     DF2    8.6  Orange1
6  2013-11-25  Orange     DF1    8.6   Orange
```

I need to find and compare the rows within the dataframe and see which columns have data mismatch. The rows that are selected for comparison should be only those which have the same "Date" and "Fruit" values but different "level_0" values. So in the dataframe i need to compare rows having index 1 and 2 since they have same value for "Date" & "Fruit", but different "level_0" values. When comparing these since they differ in the "Num" column, we need to suffix a label(say "NM" ) beside the value in both rows. Rows which have only one occurrence of "Date" & "Fruit" combination will need to have a label (say "Miss") suffixed to the value in "Fruit" column.

Example of expected output below:

[image: Expected Output]

1.)Is it possible to get such an output?
2.)Is there a fast way get it, as my actual dataset contains millions of rows and 20-25 columns?

Comment: Can you please provide your data in text form, not as image?

Comment: Are there only 2 possible values in `level_0` column (DF1 and DF2), or could we have more than 2 values for a unique pair Date-Fruit? Or just different names for different pairs?

Comment: Yes, Level_0 can have only 2 possible values

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen - I have now added the data in my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty complex, since there are lot different filters you want to do. If I get you right, you want

1. for rows that have the same "Date" and "Fruit" values, and
2. of those rows, those that have different "level_0" values, and
3. of those rows, those that have different "Num" values **to get `-NM`**. From your example you want to do the same with the "Color"-column.
4. Rows that are the only occurence of a "Date" and "Fruit" value get `-Miss`.

First, you'll need to make `Num` a string column, since we are adding suffixes. Then we groupby `Date` and `Fruit` (1). Then, since you wanted the groups to have different `level_0` values, we make filter on that called `diff_frames` (2). Then we add the suffixes using transform on both columns if they have two unique elements (3).

```
df['Num'] = df['Num'].astype(str)
g = df.groupby(['Date', 'Fruit'])
diff_frames = g['level_0'].transform(lambda s: s.nunique() == 2)
df[['Num', 'Color']] = df[diff_frames].groupby(['Date', 'Fruit'])[['Num', 'Color']].transform(
    lambda s: s+'-NM' if s.nunique() == 2 else s)
```

Then, for the second part, we get the non-duplicated rows in `Date` and `Fruit`, and add `-Miss` to the `Fruit` column. (4)

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['Date', 'Fruit'], keep=False), 'Fruit'] += '-Miss'
print(df)


   Date        Fruit level_0       Num       Color
0     0   Apple-Miss     DF2      22.1         Red
1     1       Banana     DF1   22.1-NM      Yellow
2     1       Banana     DF2  122.1-NM      Yellow
3     2  Celery-Miss     DF1      10.2       Green
4     3       Orange     DF1       8.6   Orange-NM
5     3       Orange     DF2       8.6  Orange1-NM
6     4  Orange-Miss     DF2       8.6      Orange
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try this out. Your result set is definitely how i expect them to be.

Comment: This worked great! It took 2.75 mins for a dataset with 24000 rows and 28 columns.  Is that a reasonable time in your opinion?